# JUnit testing a void method?

Tags: java, junit

I have a public static void method called dealDeck() that takes objects from an ArrayList called deck and separates and places them into 4 different ArrayLists based on their position in the list. Is there a JUnit test to check that the method is functioning as planned?

```
public static void dealDeck() {
    for (int i=0; i<28; i++) {
        if (i%4 == 0){
            playerOneHand.add(deck.get(i));
        }
        else if (i%4 == 1) {
            playerTwoHand.add(deck.get(i));
        }
        else if (i%4 == 2) {
            playerThreeHand.add(deck.get(i));
        }
        else if (i%4 == 3) {
            playerFourHand.add(deck.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Can or should this method be tested?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, and yes it should...

To be more helpful though: I'd just make assertions on the `player*Hand` `Object`s.  (I'm not going to comment on the fact that you should probably make the hands parameters to your method, so that it can be used more globally).  Something like the following should work (some of the methods aren't written, but I'm hoping you can guess what they do from the names):

```
@Test
public void testHandsAreAsExpected() {
    player*Hand.clear();
    initialiseDeckInSuitRotationOrder(); // Heart, Diamond, Club, Spade, ...

    DeckDealer.dealDeck();

    checkHandAllOfSuit(player1Hand, Suits.HEARTS);
    // Repeat for other hands
}
```

I've assumed we're talking about normal playing cards here, but as long as you can assert on what the deal *should* have done with the deck in it's initialised state, that should be fine for whatever type of 'deck' and 'hand' you're dealing with.